# Php echo hyperlink error with br

Tags: php, html, mysql, hyperlink, echo

Issue 1:
In echo of php hyperlink working correctly,but linked to localhost(testing servor).Check:

```
echo '<a href> <div class="ws14"><span class="city"><br>' . $row['fura'] . '</br></span></div></a>';
```

When i got results displayed it is hyperlinked as i want and when click on it,it goes to **localhost/trial.php** (my testing script).Not going to hyperlinked url i have echoed.Please specify.For example if i echoed google.com then on clicking it must connect to that,but connecting to my localhost/trial.php.Thanks in advance.

Issue 2:
In br tag,we can specify difference between two line.I had done like:

```
.br {
        line-height: 4; visibility:hidden;
     }
```

And this is working correctly.But somehow, in same page we need 2 different br tags distance then how to do that?
For example in above it is simply l**ine height of 4**,now in other paragraph same page it require **line height 8** with br tag,so how to do that? If i use br tags in both which br tag it will connect like of 8 or 4?
It may be bad question but very irritating.In short: how to use br tags in both with different dimensions(heights) in same page?

Comment: Two questions should be asked in two separate posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for issue 1:

```
echo '<a href='. $row["fura"] .' > <div class="ws14"><span class="city"><br>' . $row['fura'] . '</br></span></div></a>';
```

for issue 2:

your br is class not a tag. so you have to apply css style to your div element. you can't give line-height to br tag. like as follows:

```
.brclass1
{
     line-height: 4; visibility:hidden;
}

.brclass2
{
     line-height: 8; visibility:hidden;
}
```

Apply particular div tag to class example as:

```
<div class="brclass1" >your content </div>
```

and other div element

```
<div class="brclass2" />your content </div>
```

Comment: For your solution of br tag is great,now for issue 1,if i echo 500 url in browser then, how can i add href self in every query? Yuor solution of href="" i knew already.What i  want if i fetch 100 url stored in db then on clicking that they must connet to url,not like i give href?

Comment: Closing `</br>` tag is not valid HTML. I don't know what OP is trying to do with this tag but I think you should remove it from your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're href has no parameters

```
 echo '<a href=" '.$row["url"] .' "> <div class="ws14"><span class="city">' . $row['fura'] .'<br/></span></div></a>'; //google.com is just an example
```

Br is not a class it is a tag. I don't know what you are trying to do with **br** tag. If you want to style your `$row['data']. Get your **divs** element.

For example:

```
  .ws14 {
      //your css here
   }

   .city{
      //your css here
   }
```

Comment: Ok @aldrin i understood.

Comment: For your solution of br tag is great,now for issue 1,if i echo 500 url in browser then, how can i add href self in every query? Yuor solution of href="" i knew already.What i  want if i fetch 100 url stored in db then on clicking that they must connet to url,not like i give href?